# How to not store Thunderbirds emails in the roaming profile for a domain user?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, roaming-profiles

I'm on Windows 7 Pro x64 in the company domain with enabled roaming profiles.

My Thunderbird mailbox is roughly 8GB in size and synced to our Windows server on every logout, because Thunderbird puts the data into `AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\myprofile\ImapMail`.

I actually want the complete remote imap mailbox synced on my profile, but I do **not** want this all additionally synced to the Windows server.

How can I configure Thunderbird to put the data e.g. under `AppData\Local`?

And if that's possible, is there a straight forward way to migrate this, given the current setup? Or do I just have to re-configure Thunderbird, copy the mailbox locally and be done with?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the question over at forums.mozillazine.org and got the solution from [Lee_Dailey](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=12103985#p12103985):

> [Moving your mail storage location - Thunderbird - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_mail_storage_location_-_Thunderbird)

In my case I copied everything from `AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\myprofile\ImapMail` to `AppData\Local\Thunderbird\Profiles\myprofile\ImapMail-nonRoaming`, changed the paths in the Thunderbird options, restarted, verified that it worked and then deleted the old folder.